# Can I upgrade my copy of GTAV to a Collector's Edition or Special Editon?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Now I've realised how much I love GTAV, I'd really appreciate the extras that come from owning the Special Edition or Collector's Edition:

- 5 Stunt Plane Trials
- Special Ability bar generates 25% faster
- Bonus Bonus Outfit, Tattoo and Item of Clothing for Michael, Trevor and Franklin
- Additional weapons: .50 Caliber Pistol, Bullpup Shotgun, Hammer
- Additional Vehicles: CarbonRS motorbike, Hotknife (1930's style hotrod)

For use in GTA Online:

- Special Custom Characters to act as "parents" of your character (Niko Bellic from GTAIV, and Claude and Misty from GTA III.)
- Khamelion high-end car

Is there any way to upgrade my current account (save game, etc) to a Special Edition or Collector's Edition?

Comment: About the special parent: I own the normal edition and got *John Marston* from *Red Dead Redemption* as grandfather by chance. I wonder who that special parent from the special edition is supposed to be...

Comment: Nice! I wish I'd had Marston as a grandparent. My guy looks like McLovin. According to RS the new parents are: Niko Bellic (from GTAIV), and Claude and Misty from Grand Theft Auto III.

Comment: Sounds like those extras might be DLC content. You're gonna have to buy either one to get the bonuses. Rockstar may release them later on but, those that get the special/ collectors edition get the DLC for an exclusive time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually Rockstar releases these bonuses as DLC later, but you might have a while to wait. For example the Red Dead Redemption pre-order bonuses became available as paid-DLC about a year after the game's release (Release May 2010, DLC April 2011).

Source: http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Pre-order_bonuses

Answer (score 1):

[With the release of the Enhanced Edition](https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52337/details-on-exclusive-content-for-returning-gtav-players-on), this content is available on the PC, PS4 and Xbox One versions of the game for users that have played the PS3 and Xbox 360 versions:

> Furthermore, if you missed out on your chance to buy a CE or SE the last time around, we will also make all of that content available for all players on PS4, Xbox One and PC to earn and acquire with in-game cash (original SE and CE owners will not have to spend any in-game cash to obtain them, they will automatically be accessible upon upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

You are likely able to simply buy the collector's edition and then play your current gamesave on it. The game should realise that you've done this, and reward you accordingly.